# Get values of dynamic input fields

Tags: html, angular

I have this HTML template:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div data-role="dynamic-fields">
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="field-name">Link </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field-name" placeholder="Link" 
                            [(ngModel)]="HrefLink" name="HrefLink">
                        </div>
                        <span>-</span>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="field-value">Label</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Label" placeholder="Label" 
                            [(ngModel)]="HrefLabel" name="HrefLabel">
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-role="remove">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-role="add">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>  <!-- /div.form-inline -->
                </div>  <!-- /div[data-role="dynamic-fields"] -->
            </div>  <!-- /div.col-md-12 -->
        </div>  <!-- /div.row -->
    </div>
```

In this simple form, I can add one or more inputs. This is the live example: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/VPRlZ

My question is: How can I get the values of all added fields inside my `angular component` ? I can add the directive `ngModel` like above in every input but then all directives will have the same name and I'll not get all values?
Unfortunately, I can't place the `ngModel` in a higher level in the `div` of `form-group` ...
Please tell me if my question is clear or you need more information.

Comment: Check "Reactive Forms" and "FormArray". I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: look at https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form for dynamic forms should help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not you base the quantity of input in an array of Objects(InputModel it is a custom interface or class) and finally use *ngfor to show them.

**InputModel**

```
{
  input_value: string,
  index_of: number,
  isDelete: boolean, //if false is "+" if true is  "x"
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
inputValues: InputModel[] = [];
count: number = 0;

OnInit{
  this.inputValues.push({
      input_value:"",
      index_of: this.count,
      isDelete: true
  });
}
addMore(){
   this.inputValues.push({
      input_value:"",
      index_of: this.count++,
      isDelete: false
  });
}
```

**Html Template**

```
<div *ngFor="let input of inputValues">
    <input [(ngModel)]="input.input_value" />
    <!-- TODO button with 'x' or '+' depends of input.isDelete -->
</div>
```